# How to Import an Online Wallet to Parity?

Tags: parity, ether.li

I wanted to Import my Ethereum Online Wallet (ether.li) to Parity. I created 2 Accounts with the private keys and 1 Wallet with the Wallet Address. How can I transfer my funds to another Wallet (myetherwallet)? Thanks guys

Comment: Did you solve the Problem? Gruß

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to transfer to parity if you don't want to. You can just import the MyEthereumWallet into Parity.

When you import the keys, the funds should show up in parity. If they haven't and the imported wallet has the funds, then you will need to fully sync. Otherwise, if the funds aren't in the same wallet, send the funds to the new wallet address you have in parity from ether.li assuming it needs more than 1 signer.

Comment: The Problem is that I have the wrong token at ether.li. ether.li does not support ERC20 Token and now I have read that I can Import the Ether.li Account to Parity. If the Account is at Parity I can get my ERC20 Tokens off. I have imported the Ether.li wallet to Parity but I cannot see any funds in there.